# PostgreSQL - column tracking count of duplicated entries

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a table like one below:

```
no_1   no_2   
  1      2       
  2      3       
  3      4       
  1      2
```

I would like to add a new column in this table ("dupl_cnt"), which will be equal to 0 on the first entry of each unique row, but then will mark every duplicated row with an increasing number (a little bit like serial type, but limited only to repeating rows):

```
no_1   no_2   dupl_cnt
  1      2       0
  2      3       0
  3      4       0
  1      2       1
  2      3       1
  1      2       2
  5      6       0
```

Any suggestions on what is a relatively easy piece of code to achieve that? Does PostgreSQL have a data type which can act in this way?

I will be working that into a a Python code via psycopg2 module, so if that module has tools necessary for that, please point it out to me as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think this could solve your issue.

`select no_1, no_2, row_number() over (partition by no_1, no_2) as dupl_cnt from yourtable;`